# What would an information-lossy universe be like?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, time-reversal-symmetry

What properties of our universe depend on the nontrivial fact that information can't be lost?

(Previously, I posed this question in terms of time-reversibility, which is a sufficient condition for no-information-loss but not a necessary one, and not obeyed by our universe's particle physics.)

For example, consider Maxwell's Demon. In an information-lossy universe, the demon would be able to sort the hot and cold gas molecules and then erase the memory where he wrote down his observations. Hence, we would be able to extract all of the energy from a container of gas to do work. So thermodynamics and "using fuel" would work differently, and this could lead to a less interesting universe.

What else? Has anyone written about this topic?

Comment: Why do you assume that a lack of time reversibility allows Maxwell's demons? For instance, our universe appears to be not time reversible, and it also appears to not allow Maxwell's demons.

Comment: I mean the fundamental laws are time reversible. Not ALL non-time-reversible universes will allow maxwell's demons, but it seems like if you allowed a little irreversibility,  while preserving conservation of energy, you'd allow them

Comment: The fundamental laws (i.e. the Standard Model) [_aren't_ time reversible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry#Time_reversal_of_the_known_dynamical_laws). Still, this doesn't allow us to produce Maxwell's demons, even in principle.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Then "time-reversibility" isn't really the right condition here -- what I really means is:  what if we allowed information erasure?

Comment: @knzhou revised the question based on your comments